# phpunit/dbunit not installing for PHP8.1

Tags: dbunit, php-8.1

Previously I am using phpunit/dbunit version 3.0.3 for PHP7 version, Now I have upgraded PHP to 8.1 version, and I am unable to upgrade the dbunit to the PHP8.1 supporting version. I am getting the below error and my composer.json file is below. Please Can anyone tell me, does dbunit supports php8.1 version or How can I install the dbunit version that is supporting php8.1

"require-dev": {
"phpunit/phpunit": "9.5.0",
"phpunit/dbunit": "3.0.3"

```
},
```

[image]

Comment: check you `php -v` and make sure that for v4 is php ^7.1 and v3 is ^7.0 (so php 8 will be fine on both versions of dbunit).

Comment: Hi @francisco, I didn't understand your above mentioned point, I am using PHP8.1, which dbunit version would be fine for this?

Comment: for dbunit v4 is php ^7.1 and dbunit v3 is ^7.0, if you do have php 8 so is fine on both versions of dbunit ..

Answer (score 0):

The package is **abandoned** and **no longer maintained**. Still the v3.0.3 requires the following:

```
php: ^7.0
ext-pdo: *
ext-simplexml: *
phpunit/phpunit: ^6.0
symfony/yaml: ^3.0 || ^4.0
```

Reference from [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/dbunit#3.0.3).

Comment: Thanks for the info, May I know what should I do now, Should I have to use another DB testing library for php8.1 version?

Comment: I would recommend use something that is maintained and free of bugs/issues. You can search `dbunit alternatives` on google and find lots off solutions for example [here](https://php.libhunt.com/).